# jQuery UI Tabs get script on tab click and page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Testing UI tabs for first time for a personal project. Included what i have so far. I need to load 2 separate script which creates a div when i click Tab 2 and Tab 3. I was doing this before using jQuery getScript when i had an onclick function for some links. Can this be done is similar fashion using UI Tabs ? If so , how ?

```
<li><a onclick="loadTabtwo()">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a onclick="loadTabthree()">Tab 3</a></li>

function loadTabtwo() {
     $.getScript("//tab2.js");
}
function loadTabthree() {
     $.getScript("//tab3.js");
}
```

Here is my function to activate tabs and to have current tab reload of page refresh.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var index = 'qpsstats-active-tab';
    var dataStore = window.sessionStorage;
    var oldIndex = 0;
    try {
        oldIndex = dataStore.getItem(index);
    } catch(e) {} 
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        active: oldIndex,
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            var newIndex = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
            try {
                dataStore.setItem( index, newIndex );
            } catch(e) {}
        }
    });
});
```

Here is HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Tab 1 Content Here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    Load Script 2 Here - loadTabtwo()
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    Load Script 3 Here - loadTabthree()
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want but i don't think what you already have is the best practice since each time you are gonna click on the tab it will get the script again

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    active: oldIndex,
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        // ui.newTab.index() gets the index of which tab is active
        //watch the index start from 0
        if(ui.newTab.index()==1){
             $.getScript("//tab2.js");
        }
        else if(ui.newTab.index()==1){
            $.getScript("//tab3.js");
        }

        var newIndex = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
        try {
            dataStore.setItem( index, newIndex );
        } catch(e) {}
    }
});
```

Comment: Fadi , you are correct. I'd rather not have all the scripts running at one time if a user clicks on every tab. Is there a way to getScript for current tab and disable all others ? So basically load and unload the script on tab click ?

Comment: there is a way but I don't believe if you do that it will be best practice can you tell what you are trying to achieve ?? why is the script need to load in certain page only ? whats the problem of loading them once instead of each time adding a script and remove a script - which is a time consuming for no reason

Comment: On page refresh , the current tab loads , but the script doesn't refire , anyway to combine .load and getScript , so on page refresh the current tab script is loaded ?

Comment: how about to call this function 
 $.getScript('//tab'+$('#tabs').tabs( "option", "active" );+'.js')
on load of page

Comment: $('#tabs').tabs( "option", "active" ); returns index of active page even after refresh i guess thats what you need right ?

Comment: tried adding this in head and foot of page and didn't work $.getScript('//tab'+$('#tabs').tabs( "option", "active" );+'.js');  , does it need to be inside the tab function ?

Comment: i don't think so i belive if you put in $(document).ready(function(){
here
}) it will work